# Using GUI builder for frame with variable components

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to use Netbeans' GUI builder to build a dialog box which is a grid of checkboxes with teachers on one axis and days on the other (to allow the user to quickly input which teachers are available on which days).

However, the names of the teachers and the number of days are loaded from a file and taken from a drop box in the parent frame.

How can I use the GUI builder (or not) to build that dialog box?  I can't prearrange everything because the number of teachers and number of days changes during the course of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans GUI builder is only for a fix number of components.

But you can use it to insert a JTable which will show, for example, the teacher names in the 1st column, and a checkbox in each other columns, one column per day.

JTable can be dynamically updated: you just have to create a TableModel (usually by subclassing AbstractTableModel) which represents your data. If your TableModel overrides getColumnClass(int columnIndex) to return Boolean for the day columns, the JTable will automatically show a JCheckbox in the corresponding cells.

Check out the offical JTable tutorial for more information: [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)